# Using YoutubePlayerView on ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, video, augmented-reality, arkit

I am working on ARKit app where I am detecting plan surface and adding YouTube video using [YoutubePlayerView](https://github.com/mukeshydv/YoutubePlayerView) pod on to the surface. I managed to detect surface and adding YouTubePlayerView.

Audio from the YourTube video gets played but video is not shown.

Can any one has faced the same before.

Following is my code.

```
    import UIKit
    import SceneKit
    import ARKit
    import YoutubePlayerView
     
    class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
     
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    let videoPlayerNode = SCNNode()
     
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Set the view's delegate
            sceneView.delegate = self
     
            // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
            sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        }
     
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     
            // Create a session configuration
            let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
     
            // Enable horizontal plane detection
            configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
     
            // show Feature Points
            sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
     
            // Run the view's session
            sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        }
     
        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
     
            // Pause the view's session
            sceneView.session.pause()
        }
     
        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
     
            if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
     
            let videoPlayerGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z))
     
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let playerView = YoutubePlayerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
                let playerVars: [String: Any] = [
                                    "controls": 1,
                                    "modestbranding": 1,
                                    "playsinline": 1,
                                    "autoplay": 1,
                                    "origin": "https://youtube.com"
                ]
                playerView.delegate = self
                playerView.loadWithVideoId("w277oTvoKAM", with: playerVars) // CdXesX6mYUE

                videoPlayerGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = playerView
                self.videoPlayerNode.geometry = videoPlayerGeometry
                self.videoPlayerNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
                node.addChildNode(self.videoPlayerNode)
                }
            }
        }
    }
     
     
    extension ViewController: YoutubePlayerViewDelegate {
        func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YoutubePlayerView) {
            print("Ready")
            playerView.fetchPlayerState { (state) in
            print("Fetch Player State: \(state)")
        }
     
        func playerView(_ playerView: YoutubePlayerView, didChangedToState state: YoutubePlayerState) {
            print("Changed to state: \(state)")
        }
     
        func playerView(_ playerView: YoutubePlayerView, didChangeToQuality quality: YoutubePlaybackQuality) {
            print("Changed to quality: \(quality)")
        }
     
        func playerView(_ playerView: YoutubePlayerView, receivedError error: Error) {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
     
        func playerView(_ playerView: YoutubePlayerView, didPlayTime time: Float) {
            print("Play time: \(time)")
        }
     
        func playerViewPreferredInitialLoadingView(_ playerView: YoutubePlayerView) -> UIView? {
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = .red
            return view
        }
    }
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is using `UIView` instead of using SpriteKit's scene or AVPlayer:

```
videoPlayerGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = skScene
```

or:

```
videoPlayerGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = avPlayer
```

Here are possible candidates for `.contents` instance property:

- NSColor / UIColor / CGColor
- NSNumber
- NSImage / UIImage / CGImage
- NSString or NSURL object in AVPlayer
- CALayer
- SKTexture / MDLTexture / MTLTexture
- SpriteKit scene
- A cube map of specially formatted array of six images

You also missed **`/watch?v=`** in your web address:

```
let playerVars: [String: Any] = [ "controls" : 1,
                                  "modestbranding" : 1,
                                  "playsinline" : 1,
                                  "autoplay" : 1,
                                  "origin" : "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
                                ]

playerView.loadWithVideoId("w277oTvoKAM", with: playerVars)
```

If it doesn't work, then try **`https://www.youtube.com/embed/w277oTvoKAM`**.

Also, declare your `playerView` property globally. And put `playerView.delegate` inside `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sceneView.delegate = self
    playerView.delegate = self   // a delegate for using playerView() methods
}
```

**P.S.**

A regular approach for playing `videos as a textures` in ARKit app, doesn't work with YouTube videos. But if you're interested in this approach I'm writing it here (to find out how to feed a texture):

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
             didAdd node: SCNNode,
              for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {

        let playerGeo = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x),
                                height: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z))

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            // here's how your video would be in a full screen mode
            // let videoURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/w277oTvoKAM")

            let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "Assets/video.mp4")

            let videoNode = SKVideoNode(url: videoURL!)

            let skScene = SKScene(size:
                          CGSize(width: playerGeo.width * 1280,
                                height: playerGeo.height * 720))

            videoNode.position = CGPoint(
                                     x: skScene.size.width / 2,
                                     y: skScene.size.height / 2)

            videoNode.size = skScene.size

            skScene.addChild(videoNode)
            playerGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = skScene
            videoNode.play()

            let playerNode = SCNNode()
            playerNode.geometry = playerGeo
            playerNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            node.addChildNode(playerNode)
        }
    }
}
```

YouTube videos are playing in `WKWebView` but it's 2D. To make it work on 3D geometry is a challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried making the changes as you suggested. But now its not playing audio as well. And it just shows red Plane instead of a black plane. What would be missing in my case? Any suggestion.

Comment: Made additions.

Comment: No success! Still the same.

Comment: Do you use `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w277oTvoKAM` url with `www` ??

Comment: Tried both: with WWW and without WWW. 1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= and 2) https://youtube.com/watch?v=

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200143/discussion-between-icoder86-and-argeo).